# JavaScript/DOM: MutationObserver to detect changes on `lang` attributes anywhere in the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

Is it possible to detect `lang` attribute changes anywhere in the document with one single MutationObserver?
I thought maybe something like the following would do the trick, but it's not working as expected (does only detect lang attribute changes at root element).

```js
// This is NOT working as expected!!!

const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log('lang attribute has changed');
});

observer.observe(document, {
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['lang'],
  subtree: true

  // if I add `childList: true` here as sometime suggested on stackoverflow,
  // lang attribute changes somewhere deep in the document are
  // still not detected.
});
```

Comment: I think this should work (and `childList: true` shouldn't be necessary). Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/r59aLf8e/

Comment: Many thanks @Barmar that really helped a lot. Stupid me, my demo was a bit more complex, all `lang` changes were accidentally within shadow dom in my demo and changes in shadow dom are not detected, that was the problem with my demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code (same as in the question) is indeed working and will detect `lang` attribute changes anywhere in the document.
But it is important to know that only `lang` attribute changes in the light DOM will be detected, changes in the shadow DOM will NOT be observed.

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  console.log('lang attribute has changed');
});

observer.observe(document, {
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['lang'],
  subtree: true
});
```